# RegEx giving false in console but true in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Example:

Here is my code of C#

This is regular expression demo in C# in dotfiddle.

```
string[] array = {"704000233873", "705000233873", "706000233873", "707000233873", "504000233873", "504000233873", "703000233873", "704000233873"};
string regex = @"^(50|70)(4|5)\d{9}$";
foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(item, regex));
}
```

and Results are below:

```
True
True
False
False
True
True
False
True
```

When I try the same RegEx on Javascript JS or Chrome it returns false.

```
$(function() {
    var $checker = $('#checker');

    $checker.click(function(ev) {
        var inputFieldVal = $.trim($('#in').val());
        console.log(inputFieldVal); // Alg
        var regExpPattern = '^(50|70)(4|5)\d{9}$',
            re = new RegExp(regExpPattern);
        console.log(re); // /^Al/gim
        // Get text out of div#x
        var text = $('#x').text();
        // Trim and 'convert' to an array...
        text = $.trim(text).split('\n');
        console.log(text); // ["Aldor", "Aleph", "Algae", "Algo", "Algol", "Alma-0", "Alphard", "Altran"]
        for (var index = 0, upper = text.length; index < upper; ++index) {
            console.log(
            re.test(text[index].trim()), text[index]);
        }
    });
})

<form>
    <input id="in" />
</form>
<div id="x">
    704000233873
705000233873
706000233873
707000233873
504000233873
504000233873
703000233873
704000233873
</div><button id="checker">check!</button>
```

And the results are below.

```
["704000233873", "705000233873", "706000233873", "707000233873", "504000233873", "504000233873", "703000233873", "704000233873"]
false, "704000233873"
false, "705000233873"
false, "706000233873"
false, "707000233873"
false, "504000233873"
false, "504000233873"
false, "703000233873"
false, "704000233873"
```

What am I missing or why they return false?

Any advice?

Comment: There are some differences between regular expression in c# and js https://keestalkstech.com/2010/11/how-to-use-regex-groups-in-javascript/

Comment: `'^(50|70)(4|5)\d{9}$'` -> `'^(50|70)(4|5)\\d{9}$'` (or use a regex literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `\d` in your javascript for it to be equivalent to the C# regex. It should be like this: `'^(50|70)(4|5)\\d{9}$'`. In your C# code you prefixed the string with a @ which makes this unnecessary there.

If you want these as similar as possible to avoid confusion, you could change your C# pattern to `string regex = "^(50|70)(4|5)\\d{9}$";`.

Comment: Don't you think that there already will be a similar question with "you have to escape special characters when used with the `RegExp` constructor"?

Comment: Alternatively, since the regex is fixed in the code, there's no need to use the `new RegExp` construction, and instead you could just use `var re = /^(50|70)(4|5)\d{9}$/;`

Comment: I read that with "//" I didn't know that applies also to "\\", My bad.

Comment: @Andreas I almost forgot that! But it made sense.